# Execute Bash Script at startup

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I'm working on a PC with this linux version: **"Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.194 (RK3399_WED-3399LE-V11_g8f3e4d8e8b54) aarch64)"**

I made a bash script that should be executed ad start up and to do that I tried to ways:

- Made a service for the bash script but didn't work
- Added the script part to user crontab and the scrpt it is executed.

  ```
  @reboot home/admin/startup-checks.sh
  ```

Unfortunately I must run the script with sudo, but if I add the script path to the root cron (**sudo crontab -e**) the script is not executed.

Is there something I'm missing.

Thank you!

Comment: `home/admin/startup-checks.sh` should be `/home/admin/startup-checks.sh` is this how it looks in crontab or was it a typo? ... Also, showing us the contents of your script might help us understand why it doesn't execute under the root user.

Comment: Use `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: @Raffa ot was a typo. The crontab entry is "@reboot root /home/admin/script/startup-checks.sh